# Persistent Bash Prompt Prefix Linux

Tags: linux, debian, bash, hostname

I want to have the FQDN as bash prefix instead of just using the hostname. So I can change

```
root@web: ~$
```

to

```
root@web.domain.tld: ~$
```

I already know that that is possible by using:

```
PS1="\[\u@$(hostname -f): \w\]\$ "
```

But that is not persistent - it is always the default hostname when I re-login. So is there a way to make this persistent?

Comment: where is PS1 being set in the first place? how could you _override_ it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @dawud and @EsaJokinen comments I found a solution. Replacing

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

with

```
PS1="\[\u@$(hostname -f): \w\]\$ "
```

in

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

does the job on Debian 7

Comment: That's the system-wide configuration file. Usually someone would edit their own `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.profile` to make this kind of change.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the line you use to `~/.bash_profile` to have it set your profile on every new session.

Comment: I tried that already - but when I re-login nothing changes. I am restarting my root now to test if that fixes it.

Comment: To make this more relevant to Serverfault I would suggest adding it to `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to make it default for every new user.